# loading coming until image is ready and image hidden until it is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a script in which loading comes until the image is ready and only when the image is fully loaded, the loading hides and the image is shown.

But, it is not happening as I planned, here is my Code

**HTML**

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="loading.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loading.css"/>

<body>    
    <img id="image" src="http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/car11.jpg"/>
    <img id="loading" src="loading.gif"></img>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($("#image").ready()) {
    // code
    $("#image").show();
} else {
    $("#image").hide();
}

if ($("#image").ready()) {
    // code
    $("#loading").hide();
} else {
    // code
    $("#loading").show();
}
```

**CSS**

```
#loading {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPbU8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
<script>
    function ImageLoad($this){    
     $($this).show();
     $('#loading').hide(); 
     console.log('image loaded');

}    
</script>
<img id="image" src="http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/car11.jpg" style="display:none;"  onload="ImageLoad(this)"/>
<img id="loading" src="http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif"></img>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TPbU8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**html:**

```
<div class="loader"></div>
<img id="image" src="http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/car11.jpg"/>
```

**Css:**

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif') 50% 50% no- repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

**jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
 });
```

Check demo here: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ4RR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle to work correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/TPbU8/3/

```
if ($("#image").ready()) {
//code
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#image").show();
}
```

**Note: Also when you are writing a JQuery code doent forget to load JQuery library.Also just to prevent cached image from diplaying i just added a get value at the end of the image.**